# Efficient way to avoid modifying parameter by inplace operation

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a `model` which has **noisy linear layers** (for which you can sample values from a `mu` and `sigma` parameter) and need to create two decorrelated outputs of it.

This means I have something like:

```py
model.sample_noise()
output_1 = model(input)

with torch.no_grad():
     model.sample_noise()
     output_2 = model(input)
```

`sample_noise` actually modifies weights attached to the `model` according to a normal distribution.

But in the end this leads to

> RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been
>   modified by an inplace operation

The question actually is, what's the best way to avoid modifying these parameters. I could actually deepcopy the model every iteration and then use it for the second forward pass, but this does not sound very efficient to me.

Comment: where exactly does the error occur? what line?

Comment: In the end, this happens at ``loss.backward()`` -- and thanks to ``torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)`` I can trace it back to the noisy linear layers, the exact line: ``F.linear(inp, self.weight_mu + self.weight_sigma * self.weight_epsilon, self.bias_mu + self.bias_sigma * self.bias_epsilon)`` for which it says ``The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later.``.

Comment: in the context of variational autoencoders the solution to this problem is known as the "reparameterizarion trick". It's quite intuitive, see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199605/how-does-the-reparameterization-trick-for-vaes-work-and-why-is-it-important) on cross validated. It's effectively the same as what @Jatentaki is proposing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to have a linear layer with matrix `M` and then create two outputs

```
y_1 = (M + μ_1) * x + b
y_2 = (M + μ_2) * x + b
```

where `μ_1, μ_2 ~ P`. The simplest way would be, in my opinion, to create a custom class

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch import nn

class NoisyLinear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_in, n_out):
        super(NoisyLinear, self).__init__()

        # or any other initialization you want
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(n_out, n_in))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(n_out))

    def sample_noise(self):
        # implement your noise generation here
        return torch.randn(*self.weight.shape) * 0.01

    def forward(self, x):
        noise = self.sample_noise()
        return F.linear(x, self.weight + noise, self.bias)

nl = NoisyLinear(4, 3)
x = torch.randn(2, 4)

y1 = nl(x)
y2 = nl(x)

print(y1, y2)
```